# converting character encoding using a posix c function

Tags: c, posix, character-encoding

Is there a standard posix C function to convert encodings, say from windows-1251 to utf-8 and back?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's `iconv()`.

References:

- http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv.html
- http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv_open.html
- http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv_close.html